# unordered_map - Implicit instantiation of undefined template

Tags: c++, unordered-map

My C++ is rusty. I  have a member variable that is a `unordered_map<some_enum_type, string>`.

I am trying to populate the map in the class constructor. What am I doing wrong here?

From the my header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef enum{
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
}http_verb;

class CouchServer{
    string host;
    int port;
    string dbname;
    unordered_map<http_verb,string> req_types;
public:
```

My constructor implementation:

```
 CouchServer::CouchServer(string host, int port, string dbname){
    this->host = host;
    this->port = port;
    this->dbname = dbname;
    this->req_types = {
        {req_types[GET], "GET"},
        {req_types[POST], "POST"},
        {req_types[PUT], "PUT"},
        {req_types[DELETE],"DELETE" }
    };
   }
```

**Update:**

After reading the provided answers and comments I have changed my header to look like:

```
    class CouchServer{
    string host;
    int port;
    string dbname;
    unordered_map<http_verb,string> req_types;
public:
    CouchServer(std::string host, int port, std::string dbname)
    : host(std::move(host))
    , port(port)
    , dbname(std::move(dbname))
    , req_types{
        { http_verb::GET, "GET" },
        { http_verb::POST, "POST" },
        { http_verb::PUT, "PUT" },
        { http_verb::DELETE, "DELETE" }
    }
    {  }
```

The same issue persists. I should mention I am trying to compile this code using XCode 4, that is to say *Apple LLVM compiler 4.2*.

Comment: You need to create a simple, self contained, compiling example.  This means you need to delete lines of code one by one (or in pairs -- delete the `std::string host;` line together with the `host(std::move(host))` initializer, each time checking to see if you still get the same compiler error.   When you have no more code to delete, and the error still occurs, you are at a short, self contained, compiling example that demonstrates your problem.  This is required because we aren't going to read over 1000s of lines of code, and you do not know what lines *actually matter* when you make it short.

Comment: could you give the error message? I don't really have a mac here to test things out.

Answer (score 2):

That might be a compiler limitation. Something similar works for me in GCC 4.7.2, and the standard does indeed say that there's an assignment operator that takes an initializer list.

But you shouldn't be doing any assignment in a constructor! Much better to use the constructor-initializer list:

```
CouchServer(std::string host, int port, std::string dbname)
: host(std::move(host))
, port(port)
, dbname(std::move(dbname))
, req_types { { http_verb::GET, "GET" } }  // etc.
{  }
```

(And of course never, ever, ever say `abusing namespace std;` in a header file.)

You'll have to specialize `std::hash` for your enum; casting to a suitable integral type should do the trick.

Comment: How do you access `req_types[GET]` in an initializer list? I thought `req_types` is empty at the time of construction. Did you mean `http_verb::GET`? Anyway, this doesn't help solve `std::hash is not specialized for http_verb` (I'm also using gcc 4.7.2).

Comment: the way you write the member initializer looks like how they write things in Haskell. Is it common in C++ too?

Comment: @Ixanezis: Yeah, I did. And you have to specialize `std::hash`, of course.

Comment: "abusing namespace std;" Why not? I'm interested :)

Comment: @didierc: I like this style because it indents nicely and is easy to edit line-wise...

Comment: I changed my header to look like your example but I get the error when compiling

Comment: the problem with using namespace in headers is that it impose the use to all the translation units including the header, not just the one implementing it. It kind of negates the gain obtained by namespaces.